# trigonometric expression in phased array

Tags: phase

i have tried to develop the angles in the diagram bellow.
there is not triangle where we have 90 degrees phi and theta together.
why phi=90-theta  ?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are asking

> why is \$\theta = 90^\circ - \varphi \$?

This is actually a purely math specific question, so perhaps you should have asked it mathematics stack exchange instead. Anyway have a look of the sketches below

[image]

It should be clear that

$$90^\circ = \theta+\varphi $$
Which simply becomes
$$90^\circ-\varphi = \theta $$

Does that answer your question?

Comment: In what triangle in the diagram we have theta and phi like that?
I cant understant it from the lecture.

Comment: You have two triangles to focus on: First one has sides \$r_1 , \: r , \: d/2 \$. Second one has sides \$r_2 , \: r. \: d/2 \$. The first triangle's angle \$\theta \$ is the angle between \$r \$ and *vertical*. The second triangle's angle \$\phi \$ is the angle between \$r \$ and *horizontal*.